# Using multiple schemas in dbt Cloud based on postgresql instance

Tags: postgresql, schema, etl, dbt

I am using dbt Cloud to complete the tutorial to learn more about the tool.  I'm using Postgresql because I don't have any access to the paid tools that are heavily supported.

I have `orders` and `customers` in the `jaffle_shop` schema and `payment` in the `stripe` schema.  I have the following staging table for payment:

```
with payment as (
    select 
        orderid as order_id,
        amount
    from dbt.stripe.payment
)

select * from payment
```

When I try to do the simple pull to test:

```
with payments as (
    select * from {{ref('stg_payments')}}
)

select * from payments
```

I get an error.  I try the compile it keeps insisting on going back to the `jaffle_shop` default schema, even though I've been more specific about using `stripe` as above (compiled output below with wrong schema):

```
with payments as (
    select * from "dbt"."jaffle_shop"."stg_payments"
)

select * from payments
limit 500
/* limit added automatically by dbt cloud */
```

Is there something I should do differently to make it go to the correct schema?  Or is this a limit of dbt Cloud and Postgresql?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `config` to the `stg_payments` model to tell dbt to build that model in another schema. See the [Docs for Custom Schemas](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-custom-schemas)

So in `stg_payments.sql`:

```sql
{{ config(schema='stripe') }}
...
```

Then, when you use `{{ ref('stg_payments') }}`, dbt will compile that to use the `stripe` custom schema. (However! note that dbt will prepend the target name to `stripe` to make the custom schema name, so dbt can create models in multiple dev and prod environments).

You can override this behavior (as noted in the docs), but I wouldn't recommend it, since you will lose the ability to develop in multiple environments.

Lastly, if you have a source table that is loaded into a specific schema (and not a model that is created/managed by dbt), you should reference that in your dbt models using the `source()` macro, instead of `ref()` -- the source config will allow you to specify the exact schema where the source data lives